# How do I publish portfolio items with a future date?

Tags: plugins, posts, date, scheduled-posts

I am trying to publish portfolio items with a future date (using for an event based website) and I can't see to find any plugins or anything.

I have seen them for generic posts, such as "The Future is Now" and things like that. I don't know wordpress well enough to code my own solution to this :/

Does anyone know what I could do?

Cheers

**EDIT** - I mean I want it published now, but displaying online with a future date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the publish date as the event date. Save the event's date in a [custom field](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) in the format `yyyy-mm-dd`, and use a [meta query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) to order events by that date.

Also see [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) for ordering events correctly on archive pages without running a new query.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use WordPress' built-in post scheduling ability. They have a tutorial on the subject:

- https://make.wordpress.org/support/user-manual/content/posts/schedule-a-post/

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough, see my edit above.

Comment: @RobbieSeath got it, I agree with Milo's answer in that case